# CSS h2 element with underline and arrow background image

Tags: css, background-image

I have an H2 element that I'd like underlined and with a graphic of an arrow "below" the bottom border line.

Currently, the arrow appears above and if I change the background coordinates to lower the arrow, it starts to disappear.

my code:

```
h2 {
    background: url("images/arrow-title.png") no-repeat scroll 10px 27px transparent;
    line-height: 17px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00a7a8;
}
```

image of what it's currently doing:

[image]

image of what I'd like to do:

[image]

and finally, a website link to a theme which does this properly.  I have viewed the "inspect element" on Firefox and can't seem to adjust the CSS to make it work.  :(

Website link to theme that looks correct:  http://www.joomlart.com/demo/#ja_travel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they are doing is putting a `<span />` inside the `<h2 />` tag and giving the span the border-bottom instead of the `<h2 />`

This way the `<h2 />` has the arrow as a background image and since the `<span />` adds a 3px padding on the bottom it is aligned perfectly.

```
<h2>
  <span>
    This is my header
  </span>
</h2>
```

and then something like this

```
h2{
  background: url("../images/arrow-title.png") no-repeat left center;
}
span{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I will work on making this fix.  I can't accept your answer for another 8 minutes for some reason.  Thank you!  Makes sense and great explanation.

Comment: So this means I will need to give the client an example piece of code so they can make their own H2 headings correct?  Something like `<h2><span class="underlined_h2">My Heading Example</class></h2>`...?

Comment: Just caught your edit.  Thank you for the detailed help.  Very nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a span inside your H2. Apply the border to that span and use padding-bottom on the H2 to adjust the arrow position.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to use a background image, you can try using a **pseudo-element**:

```
h2 {
line-height: 17px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-bottom: 2px solid #00a7a8;
position: relative;
}
h2:before {
    content: '\25bc';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 5em;
    color: #00a7a8;
}
```

See fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kFSvL/

The major advantage is the simplicity of the markup:

```
<h2>The Header Is Here</h2>
```

No extra tags required!

Comment: Hey that's very cool CSS.  Had no idea you could do an arrow that way.  Thank you Marc.  I had to go with the answer that uses an image due to other graphics and modifications to the arrow - being custom and potentially having lines and gradients, etc.  Very nice though.

Answer (score 0):

Make the underline part of the background image. It clearly should be from a visual perspective, so it might as well be from a technical perspective.

Comment: So is it okay to have a line extend potentially 900px wide?  Your answer is awesome and simple (which is almost embarrassing to me haha) but I was concerned about the size of image and loading times. I'm sure the size would be small but after having potentially a dozen on the same page wouldn't it be better to do a css underline?

Comment: Such simple images usually compress very well using GIF or PNG. Furthermore, they are cached by the Browser and with appropriate HTTP headers even accross page requests.